# JavaScript and C# localization out of sync in ASP.NET MVC 4 using "unobtrusive" validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I recently upgraded my MVC3 project to MVC4, and since the upgrade I seem to have a bit of a disparity between the JavaScript validation (generated by unobtrusive validation) and the .NET validation.

For example, the unobtrusive validation flags up "15/10/2012" as an invalid date... however, if I disable JavaScript, that value makes it through server side validation just fine.

Is there something I am missing? Anyone who can shed any light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.